# bun.js not working until running of subsequent scripts

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, bun

after installing the [bun](https://bun.sh/) framework I'm prompted to run the following two commands.

```
Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.zshrc (or similar)

   export BUN_INSTALL="/Users/foo/.bun"
   export PATH="$BUN_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
```

after I run these in my terminal bun is working. If I am to close my terminal, reopen and run `bun --help` I see `zsh: command not found: bun`

until I run the two following commands from above again. How can I resolve this to not have to repeat those commands?

Comment: Did you add them to `$HOME/.zshrc` (or other appropriate shell startup file), as the instructions say to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you running those export statements from your current shell / cli than those are available only in the current shell environment. It's not available in any other shell you launch.

You need to put them in your `~/.zshrc` so they are exported in every shell environment you launch.
Or you can just put them in your `~/.profile` ( or `~/.zprofile` , whichever you are using) and do `source ~/.[z]profile` and it would be available in every subsequent shell you launch.

Comment: right okay so i'm a big noob when it comes to this. Following your instructions I created the ```~/.zshrc``` folder and added the above scripts to them and now everything is working nicely. Thanks!

Comment: @BenShekhtman ```~/.zshrc``` is usually a file where you put all your shell configurations and settings